# Setting where die() should be printed out

Tags: php

Is it possible to place `die();` on a specific place on the page?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be ? Did you try placing it?

Comment: Not in that way. Like doing the statement die(); on the page, and print out the output on another place on the page.

Comment: You should have said so in your question clearly :-). No, it's not possible. `die` immediately terminates the execution of the script.

Answer (score 3):

`die` immediately ends procesing of the script. Any output from it will always be the last content the script outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you can place `die` anywhere on a page since it will always be the last content the script outputs before it ends processing of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it anywhere in your code that you want.